# React fetch oauth returns 401

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, spring-security-oauth2

With React i'm trying to use fetch for oauth set in Spring security. This is my code:

```
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/oauth/token", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic bXlhcHA6',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: 'username=' + data.username + '&password=' + data.password + '&grant_type=password'
    })
```

I got 401 as status which would suggest (as far as I know) that there is a problem with the headers but I can figure out what.

Using Postman everything works fine with the same headers and body setup.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What happens if someone has a `&` in his username? (Im just curious, not related to the question)

Comment: Maybe try adding `"accept": "application/json"` to headers?

Comment: `mode: 'cors'` or `credentials: 'include'` is what usually works for me

Comment: @AndrewAxton unfortunately it didn't help, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @tryzniak still getting the same error.